# Difference between ob_get_clean and ob_get_flush

Tags: php, output-buffering

They both seem to do the same thing: return the output buffer content to you and delete it aftewards.

Which one should I use?

Comment: Withdrawing my downvote because I too am confused by the descriptions in the manual (It's not perfectly clear whether "flush" means "output", which I think it does)

Comment: Patience, young padawan! It's been only 6 minutes and 10 page views.

Comment: I think the view count doesn't work because I refreshed like 10 times

Comment: @EEka: This system is not that naive - remember that it knows who you are :-)

Comment: @Pekka Yup, in the context of php output buffering, *flushing* means actually sending the data.

Comment: @EEka is now a good time to accept an answer? we are worry about you

Answer (score -6, accepted):

To directly try to answer your question:

If you wish to begin output buffering *again* after flushing the buffer, then use ob_get_clean as output buffering will still be ready without having turn it back on. (remember this can only be used if no text, even whitespace is echo'd to the browser). 
Thus for more general uses, all my programming books err towards ob_get_flush (as only one buffer per most scripts)

Comment: `ob_get_clean` ends output buffering.  You'd need to turn it back on again.

Comment: It is not the correct answer as being pointed out above. Check arnaud576875's answer below.

Answer (score 115):

[`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) removes the buffer (without printing it), and returns its content.

[`ob_get_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-flush.php) prints the buffer, removes it, and returns its content.

Both function will terminate the buffer.

Comment: Although old, but saved me loads of head scratching. Heads off!!

Comment: OP didn't get back from September Eleventh!

Comment: @revo, he did: https://stackoverflow.com/users/576875/arnaud-le-blanc?tab=answers :)

Answer (score 21):

`ob_get_clean` will just return the contents of the buffer and assign it to whatever variable you want it to, but it will not output anything.

`ob_get_flush` on the other hand, does everything that `ob_get_clean` does, but it also outputs the content.

Answer (score 11):

Both functions clear the output buffer, turn off output buffering, and return the previous buffer value.

However, [`ob_get_flush`](http://php.net/ob_get_flush) first sends the current buffer to the client, whereas [`ob_get_clean`](http://php.net/ob_get_clean) just discards it.

Comment: -1 for saying that ob_get_clean "does not change buffering options". This is not correct - both actually turn off buffering.  From the man page for ob_get_clean "Returns the contents of the output buffer and end output buffering".  Also not very clear to say that it discards the buffer.  It doesn't - it returns it as the other answers said.  Discards implies to me that it throws it away completely.

Comment: @Adam Great catch, rewrote the answer. Discard and flush are network-level terms, but the new version should clarify that.