# Shortcode output shown at the top of the page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I know this question is similar to other questions that have been posted. I have followed exactly what was suggested in answers to those questions but still can't figure out why the output is shown at the the top of the page.

```
function foo_shortcode($atts, $content = null) { 

    $datashortcode = '<div>'.(function_exists('rtb_kk') ? rtb_kk() : '').'</div>';

    return $datashortcode; 

}
add_shortcode('showfoo', 'foo_shortcode');
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing how the `rtb_kk()` function works, I can only assume it uses `echo` to display content rather than using `return`. This is what causes the output of that function to appear at the top of the page.

To work around this issue, you can capture the output of the function with [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php):

```
function foo_shortcode($atts, $content = null) { 
    if (function_exists('rtb_kk')) {
        // Start output buffering
        ob_start();
        // Run the function
        rtb_kk();
        // Capture buffer as a string
        $output = ob_get_clean();
    } else {
        // Function doesn't exist so we return an empty string
        $output = ''; 
    }

    return '<div>' . $output . '</div>'; 
}
add_shortcode('showfoo', 'foo_shortcode');
```

#### Alternative method

If you're able to use the `bcn_display()` instead of the `rtb_kk()` method you're using, then there is no need to rely on `ob_get_clean()`.

```
function foo_shortcode($atts, $content = null) { 
    if (function_exists('bcn_display')) {
        // Return the output as a string so we can control when it's displayed
        $output = bcn_display( true );
    } else {
        // Function doesn't exist so we return an empty string
        $output = ''; 
    }

    return '<div>' . $output . '</div>'; 
}
add_shortcode('showfoo', 'foo_shortcode');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It worked well but showing dual outputs. One with wrapped in `<div>` and other without in div. Any idea why this wired output?

Comment: Where does the `rtb_kk()` come from? Is it a plugin?

Comment: @Arstik I've updated my answer to use `ob_get_clean()` instead of `ob_get_flush()`. This should return the output without printing it to screen. More details are available in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7379814/248567).

Comment: `rtb_kk()` is actually `bcn_display()` from: https://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/installation/

Comment: Updated question worked like charm. Thank you for helping :)

Comment: I'm not sure how `rtb_kk()` references the `bcn_display()` function, but if you look at the [documentation](https://mtekk.us/code/breadcrumb-navxt/breadcrumb-navxt-doc/#using_bcn_display) for the `bcn_display()` function, you can see it accepts several arguments. The first of those arguments lets you force the function to `return` the value rather than `echo` it. This would let you achieve what you need without using `ob_get_clean()`. For example, `bcn_display( true )` will `return` the value as your code requires.

Comment: Can you please update your answer to make it work with `bcn_display()` without using `ob_get_clean()` as `rtb_kk()` is added mistakenly. `bcn_display() is what i am using with this shortcode.

Comment: @Arstik I've updated my answer with an alternative method for handling your shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem, just try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function foo_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
    if(function_exists('rtb_kk')){
        $rtb_kk = rtb_kk();
    }else{
        $rtb_kk = '';
    }
    $datashortcode = "<div>$rtb_kk</div>";
    return $datashortcode;
}
add_shortcode('showfoo', 'foo_shortcode');
</script>
```